# how to make frameset tag to go to a new page

Tags: html, web, frameset

I have a few .html pages with  and they work fine but i wand to know how to make a link from the  to load a whole new page instead of in the frame?
also is there a way to stop the frames being able to be resized on the webiste?

I currently have it set up like this:

```
<frameset rows="9%,*%">
  <frame src="titles/songs.html">
  <frameset cols="10%,*%">
    <frame src="sidebar/sidebar_songs.html">
    <frame src="songs.html">
    <noresize="noresize">
  </frameset>
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function newPopup(url) {
popupWindow = window.open(
    url,
    'popUpWindow',
    'fullscreen=yes,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');
}
</script>


<a target="" href="JavaScript:newPopup('<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/site/terms') ?>');">Terms of Service</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use attribute

```
target="_top"
```

in the `< a >` tag of your link to redirect whole website

Set

```
noresize="noresize"
```

of your frame for it to be not resizable